# Is a normed topological space metrizable?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

As stated in the title:

> If there is a norm on a topological space, then we get a metric induced by the norm.

Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $X$, then $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ is a metric on $X$. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space), especially [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space#Topological_structure) to get started.

Comment: Prof.Scott,thank you very much,I think I have got it.In fact,a norm  is also a metric.But is every topological vector space metrizable?

Comment: You can define a norm in every vector space : just use the fact that there is a Hamel basis for every vactor space.

Comment: Can you show me in more details?

Comment: @mathon: A norm on $X$ isn’t a metric on $X$: it’s a function from $X$ to $\Bbb R$, while a metric on $X$ is a function from $X\times X$ to $\Bbb R$. But if you have a norm, then you can always define a corresponding metric, as in my answer. You can’t always go the other way: there are metrics that are not derivable from any norm. There are non-metrizable topological vector spaces; one is the space all functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ with the topology of pointwise convergence.